# Update input value based on another input's value?

Tags: react-admin

In react-admin, there doesn't seem to be any way to access the state of an input, nor to add an onChange prop to an input. We want to be able to have the user select something from, say an AutocompleteInput, and then populate a value in, say, a TextInput. Is this possible? If so, please post a code example.

Here's an example - two TextInput fields (quantity and cost) that, when the user enters these values, automatically populates the third field, amount. When *not* using react-admin, we can do this:

```
handleTextInputChange = event => {
    let {target} = event;
    let source = target.getAttribute('source');
    let {record} = this.state;
    let {amount} = record;
    if( 'cost' === source || 'quantity' === source ){
        amount = ( 'cost' === source ? record.quantity*target.value : target.value*record.cost );
    }

    if( source ){
        record[source] = target.value;
        if( 'amount' !== source ){
            record['amount'] = amount;
        }
        this.setState({record: record});
    }
};

render() {
    let {record} = this.state;

    return (
        <form>
            <Grid container spacing={24}>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <label>Quantity</label><br />
                    <TextField
                        id="quantity"
                        fullWidth={true}
                        value={this.state.record.quantity}
                        inputProps={{source: "quantity"}}
                        onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <label>Cost</label><br />
                    <TextField
                        id="cost"
                        fullWidth={true}
                        value={this.state.record.cost}
                        inputProps={{source: "cost"}}
                        onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <label>Amount</label><br />
                    <TextField
                        id="amount"
                        fullWidth={true}
                        value={this.state.record.amount}
                        inputProps={{source: "amount"}}
                        disabled={true}
                        onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </form>
    );
}
```

How can we accomplish this *with* react-admin?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you tried.

Comment: I have made an attempt to update my question based on your comment, to include example code.

Comment: Hello, did you solve your problem? i'm experiencing a similar problem and i can't make it.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? if you did, please update. Thanks